# Linking Rails App and Wordpress Blog on different hosts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, wordpress

I have setup my Rails app on a VPS and a WordPress blog on GoDaddy. I did this because I don't want to have to install PHP on my VPS. Also, my rails app is using Postgres and while I am aware that WordPress can be setup to use Postgres, I just don't want to go through the hassle.

How do I link the blog and my rails app, such that the blog is located at:

`www.mysite.com/blog`

Also, when internally navigating on the blog, the base URL should remain `www.mysite.com/blog`

For example:

`www.mysite.com/blog/article1`

`www.mysite.com/blog/category`

And so on....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that your Rails site runs with an Apache in front, here is something you can put into the `VirtualHost` part of your Rails site:

```
<Location /blog>
  ProxyPass http://godaddy.com/yourwordpress-site/
</Location>
```

In Nginx it would look like this

```
location /blog {
  proxy_pass http://godaddy.com/yourwordpress-site;
}
```

Of course I would recommend, that you add some more options to the proxy setup so that the IP address of the original requester is kept etc. Doing it this way, the Webserver already catches the request and doesn't even bother your Rails app with requests that it doesn't really know about.

Comment: The simpler solution is to add a DNS entry for the GoDaddy site.  But there's more to consider.

Comment: How does adding DNS entries help with what @pratski wants? Please read the question.

Comment: You're correct, I misread the question.  While I am not sure the proxy_pass solution is appropriate, I don't have anything better until putting more thought into it.

Comment: Having `ProxyPass` in here you can hide that you have a GoDaddy blog and everything goes through your domain, good for seeing who accesses what etc.

Comment: What exactly is the VirtualHost part of a rails site?

Comment: It's a configuration directive for the web server (e.g. Apache, Nginx) that sits in front of the Rails app and handles the actual client requests. See here for Apache: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html

Answer (score 4):

### to redirect correctly, but not hide the url of the wordpress site

#### in your rails app's routes.rb

```
match "/blog" => redirect("http://YOUR_WORDPRESS_BLOG_SITE_URL")
```

Make sure you didn't forget to add http/https in your redirection url

Comment: OP clearly state that he want his blog on the same domain name

Comment: This will correctly redirect, but not hide the url of the wordpress site.

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative is to use a subdomain (instead of a subfolder), like `blog.mysite.com`, and then it can be handled using plain and simple dns.